# MixedLM : Statmodels Implementation Concern

Tags: mixed-models, smf, statmodels

in order to implement mixedlm and see the intercept random effect at GEOLEVEL,which is the correct way and why ?

Code 1:
fixed_formula ='Tot_retail_exfac_sales ~ Cemails_opened + Total_F2F_Events + Total_Phone_Calls + (1+GEOLEVEL1)'
start_time = time.time()
model = sm.MixedLM.from_formula(fixed_formula, data=Mater_data, groups='GEOLEVEL1')
results = model.fit()

print(results.summary())

Code 2:

fixed_formula ='Tot_retail_exfac_sales ~ Cemails_opened + Total_F2F_Events + Total_Phone_Calls'
start_time = time.time()
model = sm.MixedLM.from_formula(fixed_formula, data=Mater_data, re_formula='1+GEOLEVEL1',groups='GEOLEVEL1')

results = model.fit() # Try 'lbfgs' or 'lbfgs
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

print(results.summary())

Comment: First code is nothing but OLS :
Ordinary least squares (OLS) is a statistical method for estimating the relationships between variables. It is often used to estimate the average variation of a variable on groups. However, OLS does not account for the correlation between observations within groups. This can be a problem because observations within groups are often more similar than observations between groups. Ignoring this correlation can lead to biased estimates of variance and standard errors.